# How to remove a role from a member?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to remove a role if someone sends a message such as `!color` and he

I've searched over the web and found a solution like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
      return
  if message.content == '!color':
    role = get(message.guild.roles, name = 'common')
    if role:
      await message.author.delete_role(role)
```

However, there are two problems with this code. The first problem is with the `if role` statement. It still goes into `await message.author.delete_role(role)` even if the user doesn't have the role. Secondly, when I run `await message.author.delete_role(role)`, it returns an error of `AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'delete_role'`. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Here is the whole error message:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 358, in on_message
    await message.author.delete_role(role)
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'delete_role'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delete_role` is not right. Instead, you should use [`remove_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=remove_role#discord.Member.remove_roles). Below is an example of this using the [commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html). I have also included [`add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=remove_role#discord.Member.add_roles) in the example below as well.

```py
@client.command()
async def colour(ctx, colour="red"):
    colour = colour.lower()
    if colour == "red":
        role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="common") # the role name you provided, common
        colour = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="red") # for adding colour
        await ctx.author.remove_roles(role) # await remove_roles(*roles, reason=None, atomic=True)
        await ctx.author.add_roles(colour) # await add_roles(*roles, reason=None, atomic=True)
```

Comment: Will the ```remove_roles``` command completely delete the role in discord or will it delete that user from it
Can you help me with the ```if roles``` command? It seems like to be returning ```True``` regardless whether the user has the role or not.

Comment: It would just remove the specified role from the user, in this case common. To delete a role you would use [`await delete(*, reason=None)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.delete) function. I will edit my answer to help with your returning `True` problem (in a while).